# How can I prevent from an error message displaying on netsuite? (used try catch but failed)

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to handle an error from my script.
The script stops because of the error, but I want the script to be executed.
Instead I want to use try catch statement to catch the error.

I want the error message to be shown on the execution log and the script to be executed.

To be specific, the error occurs when id is empty. But I want to create a record even if the id is blank. Sometimes, the id will be blank and sometimes it is not. But it shouldn't matter whether it's blank or not.

My code looks like this :

```
try{
      
    //my code that might fail because of the blank ID

} catch (e)
{
    log.error({
        title: "error message",
        details: e.message
      });
}
```

It keeps stopping and the error says nlobjSearchFilteris not valid or internalid is not an appropriate syntax.

Could it be that I am not using try catch statement right?
What could be the problem?

Thank you.

I expected the code to be executed without stopping, but only shows the error message.
But the code stopped executing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'keeps stopping' and 'the error says'. Once the error occurs the try block quits execution (that's the spec and 100% common sense). The 'the error says' is probably your log message. Not sure if I understood your problem correctly, though

Comment: Hi , Dmitry, yes the error says is my log message. Sorry I'm new to script so I didn't exactly use the correct terms. 
I wanted the script to be executed even when the ID is blank. (So I need to do something to let the script know that blank ID is not an error.) I will try to better explain the question  ! thanks.

Comment: When an error occurs it means there is no way to reasonable proceed with the program execution. But probably every language provides a syntax construct which allows to catch errors and either: proceed with an different path execution if it's reasonable or throw another error with a different message, more meaningful to the user of the program. So you want be able to `The script stops because of the error, but I want the script to be executed` magically just by using the try/catch. Try read some books on JS and program something in a web browser first, before moving to SuiteScript

Comment: It actually worked by throwing an error(blank ID) to the execution log... The script was for entering the csv record. Yes, I really need to study some javascript and program something basic first, but I was asked to do this at work so didn't have a choice haha.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should give context: scheduled script, map/reduce, client script, user event script, ...
2. If you know that you will have sometimes a missing id, use an condition like if/else
3. What is the id for? It's normal that the script doesn't continue if it need the id. As I can see, you are using the search function and it need to have valid filter array.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the insufficient information.
1. It's a user event script.
2. Yes. Sometimes I tried a 'if condition' first and it worked. but I want to change it to 'try catch' statement.
3. The ID is for category internal ID. The script uses search function using the category internal ID, however, if the ID is null, I don't want the script to use the search function as the ID could be sometimes blank and it's okay.